# How do I control c++ DLL debug symbols loading?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

I have an EXE application running in debug mode that loads a DLL at runtime.

When I load the dll it automatically loads the `dll's` debug symbols for it.

But when I call `FreeLibrary()` on the `dll` the symbols won't get unloaded.

That is a problem for me because I use `cl.exe` to rebuild the `DLL` while the EXE is running so it needs to be freed and unloaded before I rebuild it.

here is the visual studio runtime debug console output when I load and unload the `DLL`

```
'Editor.exe' (Win32): Loaded GameAssembly.dll'. Symbols loaded. <--- automatically loads the symbols when I load the dll
'Editor.exe' (Win32): Unloaded GameAssembly.dll' <--- Dosen't unload the symbols (I know so because when I try to rebuild the dll I get the error  (LNK1201 error writing to program database 'GameAssembly.pdb'; check for insufficient disk space, invalid path, or insufficient privilege)
```

and the functions I use to load and free the dll:

```
m_DLL = LoadLibraryA("GameAssembly.dll");

FreeLibrary((HMODULE)m_DLL);
```

now I want a way to unload the symbols when I free the dll, Any idea on how it's done ?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749092/dll-unloading-procedure and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615612/does-a-dll-get-removed-if-the-dll-that-loaded-it-is-unloaded

Comment: also this: a hack? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884509/how-force-unload-library-in-c-dev-c-compiler

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Hi, Thanks for your response, I have checked out the links and none of them refer to symbol unloading they just free the DLL like I'm doing.

Comment: You may want to rephrase the question a bit. You make it sound like the symbols are "still loaded" within the program itself, when it's just Visual Studio that's causing you grief. If you launched the app from the desktop instead of from within the debugger, it would most likely work.

Comment: I think the best you can do is disable automatic symbol loading (by right clicking on `GameAssembly.dll` in the modules view). But then you won't be able to debug that DLL at all anymore...

Comment: @Frank You are right, when I run the exe outside of the visual studio debugger it works

Comment: @Frank Yes but I want to debug it, is there any way I can make visual studio load and unload symbols programmatically ?

Comment: A better idea: if you attach to the running application instead of launching it from the debugger, you could create a brand new debugging session without restarting the app by detaching and re-attaching, this should flush the symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbols are not loaded in the app itself, they are loaded in Visual Studio's debugger. The good news is that what you are trying to do works just fine as long as you are not debugging the application.

Unfortunately, there is no way to unload symbols from a debugging session (as far as I know).

One way to fix this would be to tell Visual Studio to simply not load those symbols in the first place. You can do that from the `modules` window. However, this will prevent you from debugging `GameAssembly.dll`.

So the only alternative is to not be debugging when you rebuild/reload the dll. To do this, you have to create multiple debugging sessions for a single run of your app. Here's how you go about it

1. Start debugging the application as you normally would.

When you want to rebuild the dll:

2. Unload the dll
3. Detach the debugger by using Debug -> Detach All
4. Rebuild the DLL
5. Restart debugging the app by using Debug -> Attach to process
6. Reload the DLL

The order of the steps can be swapped around a bit, of course. As long as you detach before rebuilding, and don't reload the dll until after the build is done, you should be ok.